# Шло ей / шло к ней. Ошибка перевода, опечатка или правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Цитата из "Саги о Форсайтах", перевод М. Богословской:

> Он обратил внимание на ее костюм — темно-коричневый бархат, соболье боа и маленькая круглая шапочка того же меха. Все это удивительно шло **к** ней.

Правильно ли тут употреблен предлог "к"? Это вариант употребления или ошибка? Или, может, было правильно на момент перевода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[идти́](http://endic.ru/academic/Idti-9836.html) (МАС)
**17.** *кому-чему, к кому-чему.* Подходить, соответствовать.
*— Боюсь, доктор, не простудился ли, — сказал он тонким, слабым и немного сиплым голосом, совсем не идущим к его массивной фигуре* (А. И. Куприн. В цирке [1902]).
|| Быть к лицу.

*Красота, ум, глупость — все эти слова никак **не шли к ней**, как не шло всё человеческое: поистине, была она как бы с какой-то другой планеты. Единственное, что **шло к ней**, была бессловесность* (А. И. Бунин. Темные аллеи [1944]).

*Она была прехорошенькая, совсем барышня на вид и одета очень хорошо; платье сидело на ней ловко и очень **шло к ней**, словом — она была в полном параде...* (Г. Х. Андерсен. Иб и Христиночка. Перевод [А. В. Ганзен](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD_1.pdf/450) (1869—1942))

*Оно было снежно-белым и очень **шло к ней**, но это простенькое платье могла бы носить и жена или дочь бедного человека* (У. У. Коллинз. Женщина в белом [1860, перевод — 1957]).

*И это-то была та самая манера, которая более всего **шла к ней*** (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир [1865–1869]).

*Он был счастлив в своем костюме – он чувствовал это. Его костюм **шел не ко** всякому ни по цвету, ни по покрою, но **к нему шел** как нельзя лучше* (Э. Булвер-Литтон. Мой роман, или Разнообразие английской жизни [перевод — 1853]).

*Была она приодета, будто ждала кого, в шелковом черном платье и в легкой кружевной на голове наколке, которая очень **к ней шла**...* (Ф. М. Достоевский. Братья Карамазовы [1880])

Вроде бы все правильно сказано в словаре — варианты употребления признаны равноправными.
Стоит, правда, обратить внимание на то, что большинство найденных мною примеров с предлогом —  давнишние. Именно поэтому, возможно, они и кажутся "не совсем правильными".
В современном языке чаще всего все-таки используется *шло ей, шло ему* (без предлога).

Answer (score 2):

Допустимы оба варианта употребления. Проверить это можно, сверившись со словарём управления:

> **идти**, 3 (быть к лицу) *кому* и *к кому*. Костя, скажите вы, ну, разве **идет Маше** эта голубенькая кофточка? (Вересаев). И хотя
> узенькие, тощие усы не **шли к его** широкоскулому рябому лицу, он
> носил усы (В.Кожевников).